# Scala string interpolation from collections - n number of variables

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I want to interpolate a string pattern from a scala collection (Map, Seq, Hashtable) and populate a path to file.

```
${directory}/data/${fileName}
```

My collection is a Map[String,String] which holds directory and file values

args.directory and args.fileName

input from config file
     path_to_file: ${directory}/data/${fileName}

input from command args:
     directory=/temp,fileName=data.json

output:
     path_to_file = /temp/data/data.json

any suggestions?

Comment: use it like this s"${directory}/data/${fileName}" it should work

Comment: and the map should be like Map[String, List[String]] as value can me more than one file in a directory?

Comment: my interpolated (to be) values come as a Map Collection and for the interpolation pattern that you have offered you need declared vars in the scope of the s (sugar function)

Comment: it's not necessary that you declare a var you can use ListBuffer

Comment: example por favor

Comment: please keep in mind the my collection looks like this:
[fileName, 'someVal']
[Directory, 'someVal']

Comment: then how it can be Map[String, String] it will be Map[(String,String), (String,String)] ??

Comment: .../${key}/ ->  .../value

Comment: can you edit your question with the sample Map of input and the desired outcome?

Comment: sure, will do it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like `val args = Map("filename" -> "data.json", "directory" -> "temp")`, 
then `s"${args("directory")}/data/${args("filename")}"` will evaluate to "/temp/data/data.json"

Comment: answer will hold only if it has only two keys!! but the idea is right i have updated my answer thank you!!

Comment: Well, yeah ... that's what he said: `my collection looks like this: [fileName, 'someVal'] [Directory, 'someVal'] ` So ... two keys.